# Android Play mp3 from web link and retrieve mp3 information

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to retrieve mp3 information from web. But there is no such good example/sample to retrieve mp3 information such as Song Title, Artist etc while playing mp3.

I tried to get media information using **MediaStore.Audio.Media** ;but it only retrieves internal/downloaded media's information. I need to retrieve information from server.

I am listing mp3 file from [MP3 List](http://s3.amazonaws.com/sparklesongs/songs/songlist.txt). But I am not able to list mp3 information in android app.

Can any one tell me from where I can get probable solution or some information regarding this issue?

Comment: How you retrieved information using MediaMetadataRetriever? I was able to get song title, artist etc. For 1.mp3 from your list, Artist :Calvin Harris, Title:We Found Love (fear. Rihanna)

Comment: @zzas11 I edited my question :). It is MediaStore.Audio.Media instead of MediaMetadataRetriever. Can you give the code or the way that you retrieve that information as answer?

Answer (score 0):

I code with `AssetFileDescriptor` as example. MediaMetadataRetriever `setDataSource()` method can be called with difference parameters (`String`,`FileDescriptor`,`Uri`). You can refer official document for [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).

```
    String albumName = null;
    String title = null;
    String artist = null;
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("1.mp3");
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        albumName =
                mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
        title =
                mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        artist =
                mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("MediaMetadataRetriever","title " + title + "  albumName " + albumName+ " artist " + artist );
```

Comment: I added mmr.setDataSource("http://s3.amazonaws.com/sparklesongs/songs/1.mp3"); but it only returns this output D/MediaMetadataRetriever﹕ title null  albumName null at artist null

Comment: Are you downloaded the mp3 first to play?

Comment: no - I want to play it from web. I already set the link in setDataSource(). I also tried mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("s3.amazonaws.com/sparklesongs/songs/1.mp3")); But it also returns null. Downloaded mp3 are working with embedded media information but I need to play from web with embedded media information. In my app media is playing from web but it does not show any information.

Comment: Maybe you should try FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: actually at first I have tried FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever. But this jar is generating some problem during building project. I have tried with CompileSdkVersion 22. By the way I will try again :)